# Kentico Page not Found URL catches the virtual CSS Handler, messing up the UI

Tags: iis-7, web-config, kentico

We use CSS Handler to combine and minify our site. This is the setting in web.config for that

```
<css>  
      <add key="virtualPathPrefix" value="~/ctvresources/css/" />
      <add key="handlerVirtualPath" value="~/cssHandler.aspx" />
</css>
```

And this is the structure of the Page Not Found URL in my Kentico.
[image]

So, all the 404 errors are handled by that correctly, which is great.

**However, the problem is the Page Not Found URL is also catching the /cssHandler.aspx, even though it is a virtual path.** It is generating a 404 error, and hence the CssHandler.aspx can't load any css files and it will mess up the visuals.

Any solutions to this??

Answer (score 2):

Figured out, you have to exclude URLs under URL and SEO